# How to get the text inside the TextBlob result?

Tags: spell-checking, textblob

I am using TextBlob for spell check. Here is my code:

```
corrected_words = []

for i in data_words:
    for j in i:
        corrected_words.append((TextBlob(j).correct()))
```

The result that I get is as follows:

```
[TextBlob("me"),
 TextBlob("correct"),
 TextBlob("table"),
 TextBlob("breakfast")]
```

How do I simply output the text inside the quotations?
Have also tried using .text against the correct() function, but no success.

TIA

Answer (score 0):

I ran below code:

```
corrected_words = []
data_words = ['Swiss', 'Blank', 'leeve', "doen", "coem"]

for i in data_words:
    corrected_words.append((TextBlob(i).correct()))

    
print("correct words: ")
print(corrected_words)
print("")

print("Final strings:")
for i in corrected_words:
    print(i)
```

The output found was as below:

*correct words:*

*[TextBlob("Swiss"), TextBlob("Flank"), TextBlob("leave"), TextBlob("down"), TextBlob("come")]*

*Final strings:*

*Swiss*

*Flank*

*leave*

*down*

*come*

Let me know if this works for you.